# Angular structural directive with multiple inputs has no value during first loading component

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I have created a structured directive that takes multiple values. The issue I have is the second parameter which I add, is not being taking into consideration in the accessControllRole @Input. But the value is present in its own parameter declaration. Any idea what is going on and how can I get the value in the first @Input i.e. accessControlRole.

Here is the code.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[accessControlRole]'
})
export class AccessControlRoleDirective implements OnInit {
  userProfile!: UserProfile;
  private _accessControlRolePermission!:string;

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private jwtAuthService: JwtAuthService,
    ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  @Input() set accessControlRole(roleAllowed: Permission[]) {
    this.jwtAuthService.user.subscribe(user => {
      if (user&&this._accessControlRolePermission) {
        this.userProfile = user;
        if(this._accessControlRolePermission === 'Approve'){
          console.log('yesssssssssssssssssssssss');
          this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        }
      }
      else{
        console.log("_accessControlRolePermission value is empty");
      }
    });
  }

  @Input() set accessControlRolePermission(permission:string) {
    this._accessControlRolePermission = permission;
    console.log('accessControlRolePermission value::::',this._accessControlRolePermission);
  }
}
```

component class, I call directive like so,

```
<ng-container *accessControlRole="this.userPermissionRoles;permission:'Approve'">
         <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Approve</a>
</ng-container>
```

**In the console I see this output**

*Directive value is empty*

*accessControlRolePermission value:::: Approve*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please move the template rendering code and just set the values, in the `setter` method, please find below working example! If you get `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` please move the code into `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[accessControlRole]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class AccessControlRoleDirective {
  userProfile!: any;
  private _accessControlRolePermission!: string;
  private roleAllowed: any = [];

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private jwtAuthService: JwtAuthService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.jwtAuthService.user.subscribe(user => {
      if (user && this._accessControlRolePermission) {
        this.userProfile = user;
        if (this._accessControlRolePermission === 'Approve') {
          console.log('yesssssssssssssssssssssss');
          this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        }
      }
      else {
        console.log("_accessControlRolePermission value is empty");
      }
    });
  }

  @Input() set accessControlRolePermission(permission: string) {
    this._accessControlRolePermission = permission;
    console.log(
      'accessControlRolePermission value::::',
      this._accessControlRolePermission
    );
  }

  @Input() set accessControlRole(roleAllowed: any[]) {
    this.roleAllowed = roleAllowed;
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hbznml)

Comment: I have a situation when I use subscribe to get userPermissionRoles from backend. NOw in your e.g. the value is hardcoded, which is showing the data in the directive but when I get data from backend, it seems it loads before getting the backend data. How can I resolve this situation

Comment: @ZAJ updated my answer ideally, it should wait for the API to complete before showing the output! could you update the stackblitz with the issue and share back!

Comment: restored the code to original of yours

Comment: @ZAJ please check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ed7dql) the mock API from rxjs, shows its working fine!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256444/discussion-between-zaj-and-naren-murali).